# Any way to acces GDAL console in processign modeler in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, gdal, qgis-modeler

Is there a possibilty to use the GDAL console in a processing model?

As first step I'd like to resize cellsize of a raster and did it (without modeler) using the `-tr X Y`command.

Maybe there are other options which I don't know.

Comment: There are the [Warp (reproject)](http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html) and [Translate (convert format)](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html) algorithms in the modeler which allows you to set **Advanced parameters**. Here you could insert your `-tr X Y` command in the _Additional creation parameters_.

Comment: @Joseph thank you. But with GDAl translate, I'll get this error: `ERROR 5: -outsize and -tr options cannot be used at the same time.`. Do you know where this is defined as I didn't change anything else to the standard settings.

Comment: The parameter `Set the size of the output file (In pixels or %)` and `-tr` cannot be used together. Try making it blank instead.

Comment: this is not accepted by QGIS. But instead of -tr I can also resize it with -outsize.

Comment: Nice one! Couldn't test this in modeler at the moment but if you can use `-outsize` then great :)